# Where is the http-access.rb file?

Tags: ruby, net-http

In the ruby standard library there is a file called `net/http.rb`.

Towards the top of the page there is a comment:

```
# Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Yukihiro Matsumoto
# Copyright (c) 1999-2007 Minero Aoki
# Copyright (c) 2001 GOTOU Yuuzou
#
# Written and maintained by Minero Aoki <aamine@loveruby.net>.
# HTTPS support added by GOTOU Yuuzou <gotoyuzo@notwork.org>.
#
# This file is derived from "http-access.rb".
```

Where is the `http-access.rb` file?

I found a similar question on a [Japanese mailing list](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-list/21735) but it doesn't seem like the question was actually answered.

**Edit**

Recovered files at [mbigras/http-access](https://github.com/mbigras/http-access)

Comment: that depends on whether how you installed ruby. In my case I have it located here `/Users/mr_sudaca/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb` since I've installed via rvm

Comment: Looks like from an old project called `http-access` which I can't find trace of.  There's a comment in some other repos that talk about `http-access/0.0.4` published by Maebashi-san but I can't find that project in current-day github...

Comment: Considering Ruby is over 23 years old there's a very high probability this file is long gone. People add comments like this when intending to credit an original author who may have created some prototype library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mailing-list thread actually contains the answer: [here's a mail](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-list/20777?20625-21747+split-mode-vertical) linking to a RAA project. The Ruby Application Archive (RAA) was a very basic precursor to RubyGems (simplified explanation) created by none other than Yukihiro “matz” Matsumoto himself. [It's defunct since 2013](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/08/rip-raa/) but thankfully  the Internet Archive has archived [the `http-access` project page](https://web.archive.org/web/20011114205720/http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/raa-list.rhtml?name=http-access).

Direct links to releases: [0.0.4p2](https://web.archive.org/web/20000523102813/http://www.jin.gr.jp:80/~nahi/Ruby/http-access/http-access-0.0.4p2.tar.gz) and [0.0.4p3](https://web.archive.org/web/20000928213343/http://www.jin.gr.jp:80/~nahi/Ruby/http-access/http-access-0.0.4p3.tar.gz) (note: [the earliest version of `net/http`](https://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?view=revision&revision=588) predates both)

Comment: Nice find on this